# Xamarin Frame DescendantFocusability in Android Renderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Is there a way to set the DescendantFocusability on a Frame inside the Android custom renderer? I'm having a problem with the frame taking the focus from a scroll view that is it's child.

Comment: Are you sure a ScrollView is focusable? Maybe describe in more detail the hierarchy, and what you seek to accomplish.

Comment: Could you show us the code what you have tried? We need more details to reproduce.